# Angular 5 Routing can go to link by click but not by link

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-routing

I'm a beginner having problem with Angular 5 Routing. I'm following this tutorial http://devarea.com/angular-5-routing-practical-guide/
Also tried some other tutorials and the result is the same.
I'm on Windows 7 64 bit.

When I click the link, say, "books", it goes to the correct page showing "localhost:4200/books", but if I enter exactly that or refresh the page, it shows "Cannot GET /books".

Is this a bug? I made sure to read the tutorials over and over again.

UPDATE: I was using Firefox 52.5.3 ESR, then I tried accessing the page with Opera and it works, which is weird.

Comment: If you did everything correctly, this should work. Now, its hard to say where you have gone wrong without more information.

Comment: Apparently, using a different browser (Opera instead of Firefox) works.

Comment: Open the console in firefox (CTRL-SHIFT-I) and check if there are any errors.

Comment: Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at blob:http://localhost:4200/cce75f83-57c1-4787-b56f-175fb3498ffd (“default-src http://localhost:4200”).  (unknown)

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you fix your problem?

Comment: I haven't fixed it yet, It seems to be a bug on Firefox, it works perfectly on Opera.